# Change Object Fields with Data from Array

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

For each user in my array I want to take their positionTitle if the 'isPrimary' is set to true and use this positionTitle to replace all positionTitle's of the same user in my object.

Both data sets have 'fullName' which I think should be used as there can be multiple positions which leads me to think the positionID can not be used.

The code I have does replace the titles but doesn't work if a user has multiple positions.

Side note: if there are no primary positions I would like the first position for a user in the array to be used.

The isPrimary in the object is basically irrelevant.

My object:

```
graphData = {

  "name": "Annual meetings",
  "engagementAreas": [{
    "id": "1",
    "engagementTypes": [{
      "name": "forestry",
      "engagements": []
    },{
      "name": "houses",
      "engagements": [{
        "name": "engagement1",
        "members": [{
          "id": "e334", "account": {
            "id": "123", "fullName": "jim bean"
          },
          "position": {
            "id": "3434",
            "positionTitle": "Manager",
            "isPrimary": false
          }
        }]
      }]
    },{
      "name": "landscaping",
      "engagements": [{
        "name": "engagement1343",
        "members": [{
          "id": "e334", "account": {
            "id": "123", "fullName": "john boer"
          },
          "position": {
            "id": "4545",
            "positionTitle": "Managing Director",
            "isPrimary": true

          }
        },{
          "id": "5555", "account": {
            "id": "123", "fullName": "jim bean"
          },
          "position": {
            "id": "a16b0000004AxeBAAS",
            "positionTitle": "Managing Director",
            "isPrimary": true
          }
        }]
      }]
    }]

  },{

    "name": "community days",
    "engagementTypes": [{
      "name": "skyscraping",
      "engagements": []
    },{
      "name": "tennis",
      "engagements": [{
        "name": "engagement346",
        "members": [{
          "id": "34", "account": {
            "id": "0010X000048DDMsQAO", "fullName": "edy long"
          },
          "position": {
            "id": "3999434",
            "positionTitle": "Managing Director",
            "isPrimary": true
          }
        }]
      }]
    },{
      "name": "Juicing",
      "engagements": [{
        "name": "347343",
        "members": [{
          "id": "4546", "account": {
            "id": "001b000003WnPy1AAF", "fullName": "jeff bint"
          },
          "position": {
            "id": "35006",
            "positionTitle": "Senior Manager, Energy"

          }
        }]
      }]
    }]
  }]
}
```

Notice Jim bean has two position.
My array, whose isPrimary: true positionTItles I want to use:

```
IndividualData = [{
  "account": {
    "id": "23423",
    "fullName": "jim bean"
  },
  "positions": [{
    "id": "123",
    "organizationId": "001b0000005gxmlAAA",
    "organizationName": "a",
    "positionTitle": "Dalius Senior Manager, Energy",
    "positionLevel": "5-Middle Management & Advisers",
    "isPrimary": true,
    "startDate": "2016-10-07",
    "endDate": null
  }]
},{
  "account": {
    "id": "394838",
    "fullName": "jim bean"
  },
  "positions": [{
    "id": "a16b0000004AxeBAAS",
    "organizationId": "001b0000005gxmlAAA",
    "organizationName": "a",
    "positionTitle": "Head Recruiter",
    "positionLevel": "Senior Management",
    "isPrimary": false,
    "startDate": "2008-04-23",
    "endDate": null
  }]
},{
  "account": {
    "id": "001b000003WnPy1AAF",
    "fullName": "jeff bint"
  },
  "positions": [{
    "id": "a16b0000004AxeBAAS",
    "organizationId": "001b0000005gxmlAAA",
    "organizationName": "a",
    "positionTitle": "Senior Manager, Energy",
    "positionLevel": "5-Middle Management & Advisers",
    "isPrimary": true,
    "startDate": "2016-10-07",
    "endDate": null
  }]
}, {
  "account": {
    "id": "0010X000048DDMsQAO",
    "fullName": "edy long"
  },
  "positions": [{
    "id": "a160X000004nKfhQAE",
    "organizationId": "001b0000005gxmlAAA",
    "organizationName": "a",
    "positionTitle": "Managing Director",
    "positionLevel": "4-Head of Business Unit/Head of Region",
    "isPrimary": true,
    "startDate": "2018-03-05",
    "endDate": null
  }]
}, {
  "account": {
    "id": "123",
    "fullName": "john boer"
  },
  "positions": [{
    "id": "325345634634",
    "organizationId": "001b0000005gxmlAAA",
    "organizationName": "a",
    "positionTitle": "Managing Director",
    "positionLevel": "4-Head of Business Unit/Head of Region",
    "isPrimary": true,
    "startDate": "2018-03-05",
    "endDate": null
  }]
}]
```

Jim Bean also has two positions in the array above, but one is primary.

my code which currently does replace but doesnt take the primary from the array and update all positionTitles for the same user:

```
const accountIdToPositionDict = IndividualData.reduce( (current, item) => {
  current[item.account.id] = (item.positions.filter( position => position.isPrimary )[0] || {} ).positionTitle;
  return current;
}, {} );

const updatedGraphTable = { ...graphData,
  engagementAreas: graphData.engagementAreas.map(area => ({ ...area,
    engagementTypes: area.engagementTypes.map(type => ({ ...type,
      engagements: type.engagements.map(engagement => ({ ...engagement,
        members: engagement.members.map(member => ({ ...member,
          position: { ...member.position,
            // use the found positionTitle, or the original one that was given
            positionTitle: member.account &&  accountIdToPositionDict[member.account.id] || member.position.positionTitle
          }
        }))
      }))
    }))
  }))
};
```

My current output:

```
{
  "name": "Annual meetings",
  "engagementAreas": [{
    "id": "1",
    "engagementTypes": [{
      "name": "forestry",
      "engagements": []
    }, {
      "name": "houses",
      "engagements": [{
        "name": "engagement1",
        "members": [{
          "id": "e334",
          "account": {
            "id": "123",
            "fullName": "jim bean"
          },
          "position": {
            "id": "3434",
            "positionTitle": "Managing Director",
            "isPrimary": false
          }
        }]
      }]
    }, {
      "name": "landscaping",
      "engagements": [{
        "name": "engagement1343",
        "members": [{
          "id": "e334",
          "account": {
            "id": "123",
            "fullName": "john boer"
          },
          "position": {
            "id": "4545",
            "positionTitle": "Managing Director",
            "isPrimary": true
          }
        }, {
          "id": "5555",
          "account": {
            "id": "123",
            "fullName": "jim bean"
          },
          "position": {
            "id": "a16b0000004AxeBAAS",
            "positionTitle": "Managing Director",
            "isPrimary": true
          }
        }]
      }]
    }]
  }, {
    "name": "community days",
    "engagementTypes": [{
      "name": "skyscraping",
      "engagements": []
    }, {
      "name": "tennis",
      "engagements": [{
        "name": "engagement346",
        "members": [{
          "id": "34",
          "account": {
            "id": "0010X000048DDMsQAO",
            "fullName": "edy long"
          },
          "position": {
            "id": "3999434",
            "positionTitle": "Managing Director",
            "isPrimary": true
          }
        }]
      }]
    }, {
      "name": "Juicing",
      "engagements": [{
        "name": "347343",
        "members": [{
          "id": "4546",
          "account": {
            "id": "001b000003WnPy1AAF",
            "fullName": "jeff bint"
          },
          "position": {
            "id": "35006",
            "positionTitle": "Senior Manager, Energy"
          }
        }]
      }]
    }]
  }]
}
```

My Expected output. look at Jim Bean's positionTitles.:

```
{
  "name": "Annual meetings",
  "engagementAreas": [{
    "id": "1",
    "engagementTypes": [{
      "name": "forestry",
      "engagements": []
    }, {
      "name": "houses",
      "engagements": [{
        "name": "engagement1",
        "members": [{
          "id": "e334",
          "account": {
            "id": "123",
            "fullName": "jim bean"
          },
          "position": {
            "id": "3434",
            "positionTitle": "Dalius Senior Manager, Energy",
            "isPrimary": false
          }
        }]
      }]
    }, {
      "name": "landscaping",
      "engagements": [{
        "name": "engagement1343",
        "members": [{
          "id": "e334",
          "account": {
            "id": "123",
            "fullName": "john boer"
          },
          "position": {
            "id": "4545",
            "positionTitle": "Managing Director",
            "isPrimary": true
          }
        }, {
          "id": "5555",
          "account": {
            "id": "123",
            "fullName": "jim bean"
          },
          "position": {
            "id": "a16b0000004AxeBAAS",
            "positionTitle": "Dalius Senior Manager, Energy",
            "isPrimary": true
          }
        }]
      }]
    }]
  }, {
    "name": "community days",
    "engagementTypes": [{
      "name": "skyscraping",
      "engagements": []
    }, {
      "name": "tennis",
      "engagements": [{
        "name": "engagement346",
        "members": [{
          "id": "34",
          "account": {
            "id": "0010X000048DDMsQAO",
            "fullName": "edy long"
          },
          "position": {
            "id": "3999434",
            "positionTitle": "Managing Director",
            "isPrimary": true
          }
        }]
      }]
    }, {
      "name": "Juicing",
      "engagements": [{
        "name": "347343",
        "members": [{
          "id": "4546",
          "account": {
            "id": "001b000003WnPy1AAF",
            "fullName": "jeff bint"
          },
          "position": {
            "id": "35006",
            "positionTitle": "Senior Manager, Energy"
          }
        }]
      }]
    }]
  }]
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't fully understand your data structure, but if I assume that :

- `IndividualData.account.id` is not reliable
- `IndividualData.account.fullName` is reliable
- `IndividualData.account.positions` is an array that contains one element per `IndividualData.account`

The solution I came up with is to filter the `IndividualData.account`s that has a primary position before using your reduce, and do the whole thing on `fullName` instead of `Id` :

```
const accountIdToPositionDict = IndividualData
    .filter(item => item.positions.find(p => p.isPrimary))
    .reduce( (current, item) => {
        current[item.account.fullName] = (item.positions.find( position => position.isPrimary ) || {} ).positionTitle;
        return current;
     }, {} );

const updatedGraphTable = {
    //Long stuff to get to the relevant path...
    accountIdToPositionDict[member.account.fullName] || member.position.positionTitle
}
```

### Edit

According to your comment, if a user has no primary position in IndividualData, you have to set his position to the first position you get for this user in IndividualData. In that case, you can drop the filter part of my previous snippet and go for the following approach in your reduce:

- If the current item has a primary position, add it to the `current[item.account.fullName]` key
- Else, if there is nothing stored for the current item's fullName, add it to the `current[item.account.fullName]` key

  ```
  const accountIdToPositionDict = IndividualData
      .reduce((current, item) => {
          const primaryPosition = item.positions.find(p => p.isPrimary);
          if(!current[item.account.fullName] || primaryPosition)
              current[item.account.fullName] = 
                  (primaryPosition && primaryPosition.title) || 
                  item.positions[0].positionTitle;
      return current;
  }, {} );
  ```

Comment: Yes you are correct, so the primary positions of each member of the array is currently swapped into the objects primary position if they share the same account.ID but the problem is i want that primary position in the array to replace by the name so i can target all their positions in the object. The other issue is some users won't have a primary position, in that instance I want to use the first position that they have in the array, does that make it clearer? sorry i may have been unclear when i posted